# Fetching userinfo from Auth0 application in React Native

Tags: react-native, auth0, asyncstorage

I'm using Auth0's react-native-lock widget for user authentication, and after a successful login I'm storing the tokens with AsyncStorage.

If a user comes back to the app, I'd like to be able to skip the login and simply fetch the current userinfo from Auth0. It seems incredibly easy from the the [Auth0 API docs](https://auth0.com/docs/api/authentication) but I'm getting back the message "Unauthorized" in my app:

```
async getUserinfo() {
console.log('getting user info in getUserInfo()');
try {
  let response = await fetch('https://xxxxx.auth0.com/userinfo', {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Bearer ${this.state.token.accessToken}',
    },
  });
  let responseJson = await response.json();
  if(responseJson !== null) {
    console.log('Got user info: ' + responseJson.email);
    this.setState({ component: Temp, isLoading: false, profile: responseJson});
  }
} catch (error) {
  console.log('Error in retrieving userinfo from Auth0: ' + error.message);
  this.setState({ component: Login, isLoading: false});
}
}
```

What am I missing? I can't find many examples of using fetch with Auth0, is there a better method I should be using?

Answer (score 0):

Problem identified in the scope of [an associated GitHub issue](https://github.com/auth0/react-native-lock/issues/52). In case anyone lands here and not where the issue got solved, the problem is that you need to use:

```
Authorization: 'Bearer ' + this.state.token.accessToken,
```

<sub>Original code tried to access the variable within a string literal `'Bearer ${this.state.token.accessToken}'`.</sub>